# Interop with another function in a different class

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I would have to call C++ code from .Net code via interop.

I just wonder whether is there anyway to interop with another function in a different class? For example, in C++, I have the following utility class:

```
 class  ConvertUtility
{
    public:
        static void Convert(PointList &ptList, const list<pts> &pts);


};
```

I wish to call it directly from .Net via interop, any idea how to do this?

Note: here's [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669792/how-to-interop-to-c-with-namespace) asking about how to use namespace to distinguish between different method. But this time, I want nothing to do with namespace, only a class with static function.

Edit: Given that there are already too many functions in the C wrapper ( e.g, static extern "C" function that are callable from .Net, without class or namespace), I won't want to introduce an extra layer of wrapping, if I can help it.

Answer (score 2):

In the related question you linked to, Ben Voigt says in a comment to the suggestion to write a C++/CLI wrapper:

> This IS the correct answer. P/Invoke should only be used to call
>   functions with a "C" interface, which means extern "C" to prevent name
>   mangling, and also restrictions on parameter and return types.

Since the method is static, I see two options:

1. Write a simple C wrapper function that can be called with P/Invoke.
2. Write a C++/CLI wrapper that can be called directly from C#.

Comment: Given that there are already too many functions in the C wrapper ( e.g, static extern "C" function that are callable from .Net, without class or namespace), I won't want to introduce an extra layer of wrapping, if I can help it.